# Отловить post/get запрос

Tags: веб-программирование, сниффер

Пытаюсь написать на с++ программу для авторизации на сайте freebitco.in. Сумел только отловить get запрос с параметром home. И я не понимаю как передаётся логин и пароль. Может кто-нибудь пролить свет на эту странную авторизацию? Спасибо
P.S. снифаю снифером который поддерживает hhtps(httpfox 0.8.14).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На C# клиент для этого сайта с авторизацией выглядит так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;

namespace FreeBitcoin
{
    public class Client : WebClient
    {
        private readonly CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        private Uri baseUri;

        public Client(): base()
        {
            baseUri = new Uri("https://freebitco.in/");
            BaseAddress = baseUri.AbsoluteUri;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            return request;
        }

        public void Authorize(string login, string password)
        {
            var token = GetCSRFToken();

            cookieContainer.Add(baseUri, new Cookie("have_account", "1"));

            var fields = new NameValueCollection();
            fields.Add("csrf_token", token);
            fields.Add("op", "login");
            fields.Add("btc_address", login);
            fields.Add("password", password);

            var resultBytes = UploadValues("/", fields);
            var resultArray = Encoding.GetString(resultBytes).Split(':');

            cookieContainer.Add(baseUri, new Cookie("btc_address", resultArray[1]));
            cookieContainer.Add(baseUri, new Cookie("password", resultArray[2]));
        }

        private string GetCSRFToken()
        {
            DownloadString("/");

            var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseUri);
            return cookies["csrf_token"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е.:

1. Заходим на главную страницу - получаем cookie с CSRF-токеном
2. Устанавливаем cookie have_account равным 1 - у нас уже есть аккаунт.
3. Отправляем главной странице POST-запрос для авторизации, содержащие логин, пароль, csrf-токен. В ответ получаем строку вида `s1:5waP4QFeTkCbeQhTzn6R5hoyJKNnLu:a9f57d7a8c09c32cd6586a6187a6039314df567238617d0ac96924e5bc6785ff:1373102`
4. Разбиваем полученную строку по двоеточиям в массив. 1 и 2 элемент - btc адрес и хеш пароля соответственно. Добавляем их в Cookies для этого сайта.

На самом сайте авторизация сделана точно так-же - эти шаги выполняются на клиентской стороне посредством JavaScript.

Comment: Хорошо, как после авторизации получить html код уже авторизованной стрницы? пробовал так но не получается: Client a = new Client();
            a.Authorize("1AWU5KP5dg12M7mww2PM1Wj6aPzTFiAibA", "123456");
            a.DownloadString("https://freebitco.in/");

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, там относительные url можноуказывать, а "freebitco.in/" не корректен даже если бы требовались только абсолютные адреса(нет схемы). Т.е. a.DownloadString("/")(хотя лучше "/?op=home" - имеено на него перекидывает браузер после авторизации)

Comment: Ок я понял, хотя при обращении к корню тоже всё нормально парситься. Можешь сказать каким софтом ты отлавливаешь javascript? Просто мне ещё посылать значение капчи и мне на охото каждый раз тебя дёргать и беспокоить))

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, вкладкой Network в Google Chrome Developer Tools пользуюсь. Не надо никакого javascript отлавливать - по запросам итак всё понятно.